# Calculating SLA in Excel with time stamps

Tags: excel-formula

I am having a trouble in setting up an excel sheet for calculating SLA for my process, we have daily e-mails which needs to be processed within 48 hours and task is to find which are the e-mail which are exceeding this 48 hours TAT. From the export we have, Activity(E-mail code), Received date, Planned End Date, and Actual End Date. So I made a sheet with these variables and I made a column to find difference between the Planned End Date and Actual End Date (i.e PED-AED) and check if the values is greater than 48 hrs. But I have an issue in calculating the values during friday, because the Planned End Date will be 48 hrs(2 Work days) but excel calculates it as 96 hrs (Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday). Due to this it is showing more than 48 hrs and messing up my sheet. So my question is, is there any way to show the exact 48 hrs in excel by eliminating saturdays and sundays? I am using Countifs for this purpose, kindly help me. I can give more info on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the exact formula that you use

Answer (score 1):

Please try this in your formula,

```
=NETWORKDAYS(A1,B1)
```

A1 and B1 should contain the 2 dates. This formula will count only the working days of the week excluding weekends. Let me know if you need more info.